# Blender Cycles 2.8 Unwanted B&W/gray objects/colorless textures?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor, objects

[image: This is the node tree and viewport render for one of my misbehaving objects[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0o3P.jpg)[[image: The Gray items in the background are textured in color, but are showing up in B&W in my render]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwAdv.png)I'm new to Blender and Stack Exchange, but I'm having a problem that I haven't been able to find info on anywhere.

I have textured, UV unwrapped, and etc all of the stuff in my scene that needs to be rendered, but it is showing up **not as a solid gray, but instead in *black and white.*** There are other object in my scene that will render out in color: will pick up light and throw it around, but these objects remain in gray values and pick up/give off very little light. They will display as textured with color and roughness etc. in Textured view mode despite all of this as well.

I have tried re-working and removing pieces of my node setup for these objects, re-unwrapping UV's, flipping Normals, and changing the lights, but nothing seems to work. I'm also trying to use volumetric lighting, which I am completely new to, but I don't think that would be the problem either.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Seriously, Thank you.

And I have recently found that it's not just Cycles, It's Eevee as well. I have two projects where this is happening if that is of any help. Also Images attached below.

Comment: Please upload some images showing the problem and the node tree.

Comment: I have now attached an image and will put more as needed.

Comment: The image you uploaded is low resolution and has a language that I don't understand, but I can see a texture plugged into the subsurface value input (which is strange and could cause the problem) and a texture coordinate into the displacement (which to me make no sense and also could cause some problems). If after removing both theese nodes still the problem persist, maybe you should upload your file.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. I will certainly try your suggestions out as soon as I can. My apologies on the image quality, I'll get a better quality image as well.

Comment: I tried removing the textures from their places, and haven't seen any changes. I'm afraid it hasn't worked.         Edit: Images provided, Is there a language I could use in the screenshots to help you out? I don't know if I can upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

You plugged the color image textures (yellow output dot) into a mix shader input (green input dot), while they should be connected to a shader COLOR input (yellow input dot), like the upper one of the principled shader (named "base color").

The mix shader node, which has two green input dots, works if it has two shader signals, which have green output dots, and cannot handle color informations by itself.